# SELinux Prevents httpd Write Files

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux

I recently setup a website on RHEL7. The SELinux is in Enforcing mode. However, whatever how I tune the context, it always prevents httpd from writing. Here is the audit.log:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1488922911.038:6188): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=11773 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev="xvda2" ino=42006369 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=dir
>
> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1488922911.038:6188): arch=c000003e syscall=21 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f76f76142c0 a1=2 a2=0 a3=7f76e89b0ec0 items=0 ppid=740 pid=11773 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

It seems the source and target contexts are mismatched. But, it still won't work after I made it unified.

> type=AVC msg=audit(1488923356.905:6384): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=11709 comm="httpd" name="cache" dev="xvda2" ino=42006369 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=dir
>
> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1488923356.905:6384): arch=c000003e syscall=21 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f76f76122b0 a1=2 a2=0 a3=7f76e89b0ec0 items=0 ppid=740 pid=11709 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

**Update**

I did a restore of permission by using the restorecon command. But it didn't work.
I'm using the virtual host, I leave everything default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.hometest.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/web1
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the SeLinux permissions of my files.

```
# ls -Z /var/www/web1
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 admin
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 core
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 download
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 extensions
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 image
-rwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.php
-rwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 license.txt
-rwxr-x---. apache root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 list.bak
-rwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 php.ini
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 resources
-rwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 robots.txt
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 static_pages
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 storefront
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 system
-rwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 task.php
# ls -dZ web1/system/cache/
drwxr-x---. apache apache system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0     web1/system/cache
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Show some information about your `DocumentRoot` and the permissions in there `ls -lZ /var/www/html` .  Have you tried `restorecon -vvFR /var/www/html`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to apply `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` to the files which are written to (the cache directory).

http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/

Try

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/web1/system/cache(/.*)?"
# restorecon -Rv /var/www/web1/system/cache
```

Comment: Thanks man, it finally works after I set it to "httpd_cache_t" according to the blog you linked.

Comment: (Which it says is for `mod_cache`, whereas I assumed the system/cache directory was being used by some PHP code).

Comment: I agree with you.